# Not able to receive mails in my mailbox

Tags: g-suite, gmail

I've configured Google apps (Google services) to my domain for access mails some thing like mail.mysite.com. I've configured successfully all the accounts include admin and users also.

But here the surprising thing is I cant able to receive any mails when i sent mails to admin@mysite.com. But I can able to send mails from the same account (admin@mysite.com)to any other email ids.

Anybody knows the reason? I'm working on the same thing from the week.

Comment: @tomlog: Please don't add those tags. They will clutter up the receiving site, and in any case that is not what the tagging system is for. Just write a comment and, if you have the rep vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

Contacting google's staff would be a smarter idea.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if:

1. You are forwarding mail to
   admin@mysite.com to someone else.
   You may have done this while you
   were setting up.
2. You have a filter rule that does
   something with mail sent to
   admin@mysite.com

There is an option in Google Apps mail that lets you direct mail addressed to a nonexistent user to a catchall address. Try setting that up to see if mail to admin@mysite.com is being redirected for some reason.